# Как убрать вложенность массива в PHP

Tags: php

У меня есть данный массив:

```
    Array
    (
    [April] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Unreal] => 3200
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Real] => 2280
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Owful] => 5400
                )

        )
    )
```

как убрать вложенность элементов ([0], [1], [2]), чтобы в конечном итоге вышло вот так:

```
[April] => Array
    (
                [Unreal] => 3200
                [Real] => 2280       
                [Owful] => 5400
    )
```

Или как записывать элементы в массив в массиве с одним ключем?

Comment: `$array["April"]["Unreal"] = 3200`

Comment: откуда массив берется? из воздуха?

Comment: Сделайте `var_export()` для вашего массива

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = [
    'April' => [
        ['Unreal' => 3200],
        ['Real' => 2280],
        ['Owful' => 5400]
    ]
];

$outArray    = array_map(function($item) {
    return call_user_func_array('array_merge', $item);
}, $array);

print_r($outArray);
```